# Conversion of for loops to "for each"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Have been stuck on this for a while:
I tried converting the code below to **for each** statements,and i ended up with errors.

```
ChartClass.prototype.dataTranslatorLine = function(data) {
        jsonLength = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (j = 0; j < jsonLength; j += 2) {
            var innerObjArray = new Array();
            positionNumber = Object.keys(data[j].position).length;
            for (k = 0; k < positionNumber; k++) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.x = data[j].position[k];
                obj.y = data[j + 1].position[k];
                innerObjArray.push(obj);
            }
            dataArray.push(innerObjArray);
        }
        return dataArray;
    };
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

**Check out my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/)**

Comment: Where is the `forEach` and what are the errors?

Comment: What is a "**for each** statement"?

Comment: @thefourtheye You want that code? What i am showing is only a small piece of the code,and after i tried to implement for each on it,it ended up with errors dealing with data not defined.
So thought it was pointless sharing that..

Comment: To know where you are failing, you should show the code which has the problems and the actual error messages. Most people might not like to write program from one way to another way and they may even like to close this question as `it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem`

Comment: @thefourtheye allright.. i will make a fiddle. Gimme a sec.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK Fiddle will be good and help reproducing the problem, also sharing only the part of code which has the problem would make this question answerable.

Comment: Added the fiddle,though some error pertains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is going on, but this should be a pretty direct translation to using `forEach`.

```
ChartClass.prototype.dataTranslatorLine = function(data) {
    var dataArray = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, idx) {
        if (idx % 2 === 1) {
            return;
        }

        var innerObjArray = [];
        Object.keys(data[idx].position).forEach(function(key2, idx2) {
            var obj = {
                x: data[idx].position[idx2],
                y: data[idx + 1].position[idx2]
            };
            innerObjArray.push(obj);
        });

        dataArray.push(innerObjArray);
    });

    return dataArray;
};
```

A couple of notes though: if data is an array, there is no need to call `Object.keys` on it, just go directly for the iteration; this code is rather convoluted, and I would think that with some work on the data structure being passed in could make more sense; and a `for` loop may be better for you situation instead of the `forEach` loop since you are primarily working on index instead of doing stuff just with the values.

EDIT:

After looking at your data structure this is a quick and dirty way to do it, but I still suggest you rework how you are storing your data into something that makes more sense.

```
ChartClass.prototype.dataTranslatorLine = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
        x = data[i].position;
        y = data[i + 1].position;

        var innerObj = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            innerObjArray.push({
                x: x[j],
                y: y[j]
            });
        }

        dataArray.push(innerObj);
    }

    return dataArray;
};
```

The `forEach` doesn't buy you anything since you are working with indexes, not just the contents of the array. As for what `key` is in `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, idx) {` for you it will be the strings 'name' and 'position' since you are iterating over the keys of the object. Also, `if (idx % 2 === 1) { return; }` is how it is mimicking the `j += 2` from your original for loop, basically exiting the function if it is an odd index.

Comment: Your code almost got it.
I wish i could show the fiddle,for some strage reason, the fiddle is getting errors on my current code(which doesn't have any error on the local server)

Comment: Your code isn't instantiating dataArray inside the function (I assumed this was an error), you can try taking that line out.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work in a meaningful way. dataArray instantiation is `var dataArray = [];`.

Comment: Yeh just found out why..
d3.json is a GET process,and fiddle is asking me to do that in POST ,which i don't think is possible.
Cuz its a d3 inbuilt function.

Comment: Lemme try to work with your code.. and i will get back to you.

Comment: Jeez,it worked... that data Array instantion was the problem.

Comment: Btw can you tell me ,what if (idx % 2 === 1) {
            return;
        }
this code stands for? 

And what are key in this?

Comment: Better implementation added + answering questions.